# Creating indexes on existing entity properties

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I started off with my project, I thought there was no need to create indexes on certain fields of entities but to generate certain daily reports, statistics we have a need to create indexes on some fields of existing entities.

As explained in the post [Retroactive indexing in GAE Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008580/retroactive-indexing-in-gae-datastore), only way is to first change these properties from unindexed to indexed then retrieve and write all the entities again.

My question is if I take a back up from Datastore Admin and restore after changing the properties to indexed, will my project have all the required properties indexed? or do I need to retrieve and write through a program?

PS: My project is a java project on GAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Work around I mentioned earlier does not work. The only way to change the field is to re-upload the entities. Sorry.

Comment: I have an update related to this. As I mentioned in my question, I needed to generate daily statistics. I realized that I can use BigQuery for this instead of creating indexes in datastore. So I dropped the idea of retrieving and writing all entities programatically.