# GAE Python Query ordering won't take certain properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the official tutorial for GAE guestbook, I'm trying to change the order of query results like so:

```
greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(Greeting.content)
```

`Greeting` looks like this:

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Passing `Greeting.date` obviously works.
What could be the reason?

Comment: I suspect it may be because you have indexing turned off (`indexed=False`) for the `content` property, effectively hiding that property from queries. You may even get an error if you try to access unindexed property values directly from query results.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and still nothing..

Comment: on the same entities you had before or on new entities created after you enabled indexing? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008580/retroactive-indexing-in-gae-datastore)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes at some point there is a sentence starting as "Note, however, that changing a property from unindexed to indexed d.." check what it says